# Window-7 installation problems

Tags: windows-7

I am facing a problem in Installation of windows 7.

The problem is that after installation of windows 7, windows starts to activate and after  activating the windows reboots to restart. But it doesn't restarts, and the curser starts to blink and freezes. I had window 7 istalled before on it...

I also installed window xp on it and it got installed easily, but problem is with windows 7 installation.

Comment: This a legitimate license?  The reason I ask, issues surrounding activation, are often signs of a nonlegitimate license being used.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the windows normally without entering the Key when it asks to, simply install windows without a key with some day of trail (normally 30-day trial period). Then first try to  activate a window with a loader or activator and see if it is working fine. If it works normally then you can change the key to your key.